# OOP - Should I set the database connection as `public` for other classes to use it, although it might be unsafe?

Tags: object-oriented, database

I have a basic `Database` class, and it has a `mysqli` property (an object itself) which contains the connection information. Other classes uses this class to read and manipulate the database.

There are built-in functions in any database connection object (in this case, PHP's `mysqli::multi_query`, `mysqli::next_result` etc.), that I need to use in other classes.

The problem is that I really do not want to set the connection property as `public` since I believe it is a bad practice to do so in any property, especially not one with connection information.

So what should I do? Should I set it to `public` anyway, or should I create manually a function for each built-in function I need to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of wrapping a core PHP database driver is to provide your custom interface for handling database requests. Making the `mysqli` property public completely defies the purpose and you wouldn't really need your custom class in the first place.

The best approach would be to create a `DatabaseInterface`, have class or classes implement it, classes, which, preferably in their constructor, take a core PHP database driver (be it mysqli or PDO) and use the `DatabaseInterface` as parameters for classes which require database interaction.

This way you provide your own abstraction, over which you have full control, and are also not limited to single implementation.

---

## More details and implementation example

In PHP you have generally two recommended options for database connection.

- using `PDO`
- using `mysqli`

The problem is `PDO` and `mysqli` provide different interface to querying, creating transactions, so if you used for example `mysqli` in your application directly and then wanted to switch to `PDO`, you would have to refactor every single database call in your app.

## Use interfaces for abstraction

You create an interface, which will represent your very own interface for database calls. Here is a very simple example how *some* of its methods may look.

```
interface MyDatabase
{
    public function beginTransaction();
    public function commitTransaction();
    public function doQuery($sql);
}
```

Right now you want to use `mysqli`, so you create a new class, `MyMySQLiDriver`, which will implement the `MyDatabase` interface and either take a `mysqli` object in its constructor as a parameter, or you can use the procedural-programming `mysqli_*` functions.

```
class MyMySQLiDriver implements MyDatabase
{
    protected $mysqli;

    public function __construct($mysqli)
    {
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    }

    public function beginTransaction() { /* use $this->mysqli here */ }
    public function commitTransaction() { /* use $this->mysqli here */ }
    public function doQuery($sql) { /* use $this->mysqli here */ }
}
```

Anywhere else in your code, if you want to use a database, you are going to pass an object of `MyDatabase` (the interface) type as a parameter and use its methods.

```
function IAmUsingTheDatabase(MyDatabase $db)
{
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $db->doQuery("SELECT * ...");
    $db->commitTransaction();
}
```

Note that the `IAmUsingTheDatabase` has no idea whether you are using `PDO`, `mysqli` or anything else. It wants to use the database and it uses the interface you provided.

As I have said in the comments under this post, if, in the future, you don't want to use the `MyMySQLiDriver` anymore, you create a new class, be it `MyPDODriver` or anything else, which will again implement `MyDatabase` interface.

---

## Where to go from here

You can study more on this topic under [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) (this is directly tied to [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and benefits greatly from the [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)).

Comment: But what would be exactly the structure of that interface?

Comment: Take a look at [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it). You shouldn't make methods just because you think one day you are going to need it. If you need a method for something, add and implement it, but in your case, they will be fairly similar to the core methods.

Comment: But why create an interface? I could just stay with my class and create those functions I need. Sorry if it is a silly question, I am pretty new to OOP.

Comment: @Sipo You want to create an interface and have a class implement said interface to be able to swap out the implementation, should you ever, without changing anything else. Let's say you decide to use `PDO` instead of `mysqli` in 2 years, you will just create a new database driver implementing `DatabaseInterface` which will use the `PDO` and simply change in your `config` you no longer want to use the one using `mysqli` but the one which uses `PDO` instead. And everything will still work, because the database contract is guaranteed by the interface and not a specific class.

Comment: Could you add some basic example to your answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Sipo Sure, I can code a general example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30494/discussion-between-sipo-and-david-packer).